# How to use a jQuery function in my javascript source code?

Tags: jquery

I'm very sorry to ask such an easy question for you. I can use a jQuery function in my html pages. But I do not know how to use one in my javascript source file? Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Currently , I use the following declaration at the head of my javascript source file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in exactly the same way. You will just need to link the jQuery source file before you link the external JS file with the jQuery in it so that it knows how to handle it.

Here is an example for hosted jquery:

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
  var t = $.trim(" abc ");
  alert('...'+t+'...'); 
});
```

Here is an example for embedded jquery:

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
(function($){ 
  var t = $.trim(" abc ");
  alert('...'+t+'...'); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Borrowing your test.js, how to use jQuery.trim(" abc ") ? Although it may sounds impolite , alert is not suitable here as an example.Please re arrange test.js again.

Comment: Wow. That totally was impolite. I have caved to your request, but if you have something specific in mind you should request it in your question.

Comment: Let me apologize to you .I am very sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much .I finally understood your sample code.It works well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you're not sure how to add it to the header of the file so that it affects DOM elements after it? Like wescrow said, you should first import the jQuery file then your script file. Then, in your script file, make sure you have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // your javascript here
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
     // your javascript here
});
```

This ensures that your DOM's loaded before your jQuery code kicks in. For more info, check out the official doc: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ They have a very good example there.

Answer (score 1):

And here's a small taste of what you can quickly knock up with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  // Few lines of code will query Twitter's search API and append the results to the browser.
  var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=weather";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.results, function(i, tweet){
      $('body').append("<p>" + tweet.text + " by " + tweet.from_user_name + "</p>");
    });
  });
});
```